# VS2012 Silverlight web project not supported

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012

I've just upgraded a VS2010 solution which contains WPF and Silverlight projects to VS2012, and received this error message:

[image]

> This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types installed or does not support them

This is VS2012 Ultimate. Do I need a framework or SDK to open the Silverlight web project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question so quickly - I am being dumb. The migration report had a perfect error message. I need to install the web developer tools :0

[image]